How to Handle Rows with and without Status Changes in History Table
I have a table in SQL Server that tracks the status of different IDs over time. The table includes both historical data and current data, and I need to write a query that will return the correct status and date ranges for each ID, whether or not the status has changed.
The table structure is as follows:
CREATE TABLE #history_Card_status (
    HistoryData BIT,
    StatusUpdateDate DATETIME,
    CreateDate DATETIME,
    Id BIGINT,
    Status NVARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO #history_Card_status (HistoryData, StatusUpdateDate, CreateDate, Id, Status)
VALUES
-- Current Data
(0, NULL, '2023-06-13 05:07:38.700', 222, 'Open'),
(0, NULL, '2021-07-16 00:44:46.740', 111, 'Closed'),
-- Historical Data
(1, '2024-08-20 21:10:57.093', '2021-07-16 00:44:46.740', 111, 'Closed'),
(1, '2024-07-05 13:22:04.220', '2021-07-16 00:44:46.740', 111, 'Closed'),
(1, '2024-07-05 13:13:02.133', '2021-07-16 00:44:46.740', 111, 'Inactive/Block'),
(1, '2024-07-02 03:01:12.467', '2021-07-16 00:44:46.740', 111, 'Inactive/Block'),
(1, '2024-06-24 02:12:00.773', '2021-07-16 00:44:46.740', 111, 'Inactive/Block'),
(1, '2024-06-24 02:12:00.687', '2021-07-16 00:44:46.740', 111, 'Inactive/Block'),
(1, '2024-06-24 02:00:46.040', '2021-07-16 00:44:46.740', 111, 'Open'),
(1, '2024-06-24 02:00:44.303', '2021-07-16 00:44:46.740', 111, 'Open'),
(1, '2024-04-14 11:57:21.133', '2021-07-16 00:44:46.740', 111, 'Open'),
(1, '2024-04-14 11:52:09.073', '2021-07-16 00:44:46.740', 111, 'Open'),
(1, '2024-07-01 04:28:08.213', '2023-06-13 05:07:38.700', 222, 'Open'),
(1, '2024-07-01 03:39:54.607', '2023-06-13 05:07:38.700', 222, 'Open'),
(1, '2024-04-24 11:18:59.380', '2023-06-13 05:07:38.700', 222, 'Open'),
(1, '2024-04-24 11:18:59.227', '2023-06-13 05:07:38.700', 222, 'Open');

This table contains both historical records (marked with HistoryData = 1) and current records (marked with HistoryData = 0). The StatusUpdateDate column is filled only for historical records, while the CreateDate column is present in all records.
Problem
I need to create a query that returns the status and the corresponding date ranges for each ID. The query should handle both cases where the status changes and cases where it does not. The expected result should look like this:
StatusUpdateDate         StatusTillDate          Id      Status
-----------------------  ----------------------  ------  -----------
2024-07-05 13:13:02.133  2024-08-24 08:49:31.233  111     Closed
2024-06-24 02:00:46.040  2024-07-05 13:13:02.133  111     Inactive/Block
2021-07-16 00:44:46.740  2024-06-24 02:00:46.040  111     Open
2023-06-13 05:07:38.700  2024-08-24 08:49:31.233  222     Open

My Attempt
I started with a query that works for cases where status changes occur:
WITH Step1 AS (
    SELECT 
        StatusUpdateDate = ISNULL(StatusUpdateDate, ISNULL(history.CreateDate, '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000')),
        Id,
        Status,
        lag_status = LAG(Status) OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY StatusUpdateDate DESC), 
        ChangeFlag = CASE 
            WHEN Status <> LAG(Status) OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY StatusUpdateDate DESC) 
            THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
    FROM #history_Card_status AS history
)
SELECT 
    StatusUpdateDate,
    StatusTillDate = ISNULL(LAG(StatusUpdateDate) OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY StatusUpdateDate DESC), DATEADD(DAY, 2, GETDATE())),
    Id,
    Status = ISNULL(LAG(Status) OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY StatusUpdateDate DESC), lag_status)
FROM Step1
WHERE ChangeFlag = 1;

This query works well for IDs where a status change has occurred, but I only see IDs with changes, like this:
StatusUpdateDate         StatusTillDate          Id      Status
-----------------------  ----------------------  ------  -----------
2024-07-05 13:13:02.133  2024-08-24 06:22:39.003  111     Closed
2024-06-24 02:00:46.040  2024-07-05 13:13:02.133  111     Inactive/Block
2021-07-16 00:44:46.740  2024-06-24 02:00:46.040  111     Open

Then, I tried to handle the rows where changes did not take place:
WITH Step1 AS (
    SELECT 
        StatusUpdateDate = ISNULL(StatusUpdateDate, ISNULL(history.CreateDate, '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000')),
        Id,
        Status,
        lag_status = LAG(Status) OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY StatusUpdateDate DESC), 
        ChangeFlag = CASE 
            WHEN Status <> LAG(Status) OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY StatusUpdateDate DESC) 
            THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
        rownum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY StatusUpdateDate DESC) 
    FROM #history_Card_status AS history
)
SELECT 
    StatusUpdateDate,
    StatusTillDate = ISNULL(LAG(StatusUpdateDate) OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY StatusUpdateDate DESC), DATEADD(DAY, 2, GETDATE())),
    Id,
    ChangeFlag,
    Status = ISNULL(LAG(Status) OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY StatusUpdateDate DESC), lag_status),
    rownum
FROM Step1
WHERE ChangeFlag = 1
OR (ChangeFlag = 0 AND rownum = 1); 

This attempt, however, returns disappointing results like:
StatusUpdateDate         StatusTillDate          Id      ChangeFlag  Status
-----------------------  ----------------------  ------  ----------- -----------
2024-08-20 21:10:57.093  2024-08-24 16:44:22.340  111     0           NULL
2024-07-05 13:13:02.133  2024-08-20 21:10:57.093  111     1           Closed
2024-06-24 02:00:46.040  2024-07-05 13:13:02.133  111     1           Inactive/Block
2021-07-16 00:44:46.740  2024-06-24 02:00:46.040  111     1           Open
2024-07-01 04:28:08.213  2024-08-24 16:44:22.340  222     0           NULL

What I'm Looking For
I'm looking for a way to return the correct status and date ranges for each ID, including those without any status changes, as shown in the expected results.

Where does the date 2024-08-24 come from for ID = 222?

Looks kinda gaps and islandish.

If you're expecting ChangeFlag to be 1 for the initial history records then you probably want to handle the null case with something like CASE WHEN Status <> ISNULL(LAG(Status) OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY StatusUpdateDate DESC) , N'') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

@TheImpaler
Look at DATEADD(DAY, 2, GETDATE())) in the second part of the isnull function inside StatusTillDate in the outer query.

This looks like a standard gaps and island, with some small wrinkles, like the start date:
SELECT
    MIN(CASE WHEN groupflag = 0 THEN CreateDate ELSE StatusUpdateDate END) AS minDate
    , MAX(ISNULL(StatusUpdateDate, DATEADD(DAY, 2, GETDATE()))) AS maxDate
    , ID, status, groupFlag
FROM (
    SELECT *
        , SUM(flag) OVER(partition BY ID ORDER BY historydata DESC, statusupdatedate rows BETWEEN unbounded preceding AND CURRENT row) AS groupFlag
    FROM (
        SELECT
            CASE WHEN status <> lag(status) OVER(partition BY id ORDER BY historydata DESC, statusupdatedate) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS flag
            , *
        FROM #history_Card_status h
    ) x
) x
GROUP BY groupflag, id, status
ORDER BY id, groupflag DESC

I usually use the CASE WHEN something <> lag(something) then 1 else 0 end which takes cares of the first row.
Then, we summarize the above flag to create the grouping. For performance I use ROWS BETWEEN, otherwise it defaults to RANGE which works a little slower.
Finally, I take the CreateDate for the first row to create the anchor date, and StatusUpdateDate for the others.
Output:



minDate
maxDate
ID
status
groupFlag




2024-07-05 13:22:04.220
2024-08-25 00:04:20.760
111
Closed
2


2024-06-24 02:12:00.687
2024-07-05 13:13:02.133
111
Inactive/Block
1


2021-07-16 00:44:46.740
2024-06-24 02:00:46.040
111
Open
0


2023-06-13 05:07:38.700
2024-08-25 00:04:20.760
222
Open
0




Thank you for your answer! I have one thing that needs improvement: I need the max date for each status to match the min date of the next status, like this:
Status max update (Open) == Status min update (Inactive/Block)
2024-06-24 02:00:46.040 == 2024-06-24 02:00:46.040
Status max update (Inactive/Block) == Status min update (Closed)
2024-07-05 13:13:02.133 == 2024-07-05 13:13:02.133
Could you please offer a solution for this?

You can use the lead function to get the min date of the next group. Or am I missing something?

Thanks for the suggestion! Could you please show me how to use the LEAD function to align the dates? I'm not sure where it would fit in your query.

I made a small adjustment to your query:
^ Shows that no change was made...
SELECT MIN(CASE WHEN groupFlag = 0 THEN CreateDate ELSE StatusUpdateDatemin END) AS minDate,
...^
FROM (
SELECT *,
LAG(StatusUpdateDate) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY HistoryData DESC, StatusUpdateDate) AS StatusUpdateDatemin,
...^
The idea is that when a group is done, the MIN in the outer query looks one row above, so for the min of group 1, it checks the max of group 0.
Please let me know if this approach is correct, or if you have any suggestions!

Yeah, that should work too. I was thinking of doing another level of subquery and taking LEAD of next date there, but yours sounds good too

Your answer helped a lot, Thank you very much!


First, we mark ("Gaps and Islands") rows, where status is changed (Flag New Group fngr=1).
Order of rows by StatusUpdateDate.
However, since for HistoryData rows StatusUpdateDate is null, and we want move this rows to end of output order, we use  order by HistoryData desc, StatusUpdateDate. Subquery output is shown below in the text

With filtered rows (fgrn=1) we take StatusUpdateDate (or CreateDate for first row)
and StatusTillDate  as lead date in filtered rows (or DATEADD(DAY, 2, GETDATE()) for last row).


See example
select Id,Status
  ,case when prevStatus='New' then CreateDate
   else StatusUpdateDate
   end StatusUpdateDate  
  ,lead(StatusUpdateDate,1,DATEADD(DAY, 2, GETDATE()))
          over(partition by Id order by HistoryData desc,StatusUpdateDate) StatusTillDate 
from(
  select *
    ,lag(Status,1,'New')over(partition by Id order by HistoryData desc,StatusUpdateDate) prevStatus
    ,case when Status<>lag(Status,1,'New')over(partition by Id order by HistoryData desc,StatusUpdateDate) 
       then 1 
     else 0 
     end fngr
  from history_Card_status
)t
where fngr=1




Id
Status
StatusUpdateDate
StatusTillDate




111
Open
2021-07-16 00:44:46.740
2024-06-24 02:12:00.687


111
Inactive/Block
2024-06-24 02:12:00.687
2024-07-05 13:22:04.220


111
Closed
2024-07-05 13:22:04.220
2024-08-24 22:04:52.890


222
Open
2023-06-13 05:07:38.700
2024-08-24 22:04:52.890



fiddle
After filter with fngr=1 (flag New Group of Status) we get



HistoryData
StatusUpdateDate
CreateDate
Id
Status
prevStatus
fngr




True
2024-04-14 11:52:09.073
2021-07-16 00:44:46.740
111
Open
New
1


True
2024-06-24 02:12:00.687
2021-07-16 00:44:46.740
111
Inactive/Block
Open
1


True
2024-07-05 13:22:04.220
2021-07-16 00:44:46.740
111
Closed
Inactive/Block
1


True
2024-04-24 11:18:59.227
2023-06-13 05:07:38.700
222
Open
New
1



Update 1. An interesting point with StatusUpdateDate and StatusTillDate.
If compare desired result from OP, result in @siggemannen answer and my result



Var
Id
Status
StatusUpdateDate
StatusTillDate




OP
111
Open
2021-07-16 00:44:46.740
2024-06-24 02:00:46.040


OP
111
Inactive/Block
2024-06-24 02:00:46.040
2024-07-05 13:13:02.133


Sig
111
Open
2021-07-16 00:44:46.740
2024-06-24 02:00:46.040


Sig
111
Inactive/Block
2024-06-24 02:12:00.687
2024-07-05 13:13:02.133


Val
111
Open
2021-07-16 00:44:46.740
2024-06-24 02:12:00.687


Val
111
Inactive/Block
2024-06-24 02:12:00.687
2024-07-05 13:22:04.220



For example
'2024-06-24 02:00:46.040' - is last point where status set to ='Open'
'2024-06-24 02:12:00.687' - is point where status changed from 'Open' to 'Inactive/Block'
    Open       ?       Inactive/Block        ?            Close
^-----------^------^------------------^--------------^------------  
|           |      |                  |              |
Open        Open   Inactive/Block     Inactive/Block Close

My question is - where is point for StatusTillDate?

For refrerence.  Subquery output is



HistoryData
StatusUpdateDate
CreateDate
Id
Status
prevStatus
fngr




True
2024-04-14 11:52:09.073
2021-07-16 00:44:46.740
111
Open
New
1


True
2024-04-14 11:57:21.133
2021-07-16 00:44:46.740
111
Open
Open
0


True
2024-06-24 02:00:44.303
2021-07-16 00:44:46.740
111
Open
Open
0


True
2024-06-24 02:00:46.040
2021-07-16 00:44:46.740
111
Open
Open
0


True
2024-06-24 02:12:00.687
2021-07-16 00:44:46.740
111
Inactive/Block
Open
1


True
2024-06-24 02:12:00.773
2021-07-16 00:44:46.740
111
Inactive/Block
Inactive/Block
0


True
2024-07-02 03:01:12.467
2021-07-16 00:44:46.740
111
Inactive/Block
Inactive/Block
0


True
2024-07-05 13:13:02.133
2021-07-16 00:44:46.740
111
Inactive/Block
Inactive/Block
0


True
2024-07-05 13:22:04.220
2021-07-16 00:44:46.740
111
Closed
Inactive/Block
1


True
2024-08-20 21:10:57.093
2021-07-16 00:44:46.740
111
Closed
Closed
0


False
null
2021-07-16 00:44:46.740
111
Closed
Closed
0


True
2024-04-24 11:18:59.227
2023-06-13 05:07:38.700
222
Open
New
1


True
2024-04-24 11:18:59.380
2023-06-13 05:07:38.700
222
Open
Open
0


True
2024-07-01 03:39:54.607
2023-06-13 05:07:38.700
222
Open
Open
0


True
2024-07-01 04:28:08.213
2023-06-13 05:07:38.700
222
Open
Open
0


False
null
2023-06-13 05:07:38.700
222
Open
Open
0




An explanation (e.g. see other answer) would significantly improve your answer.

@ValNik Thank you for your answer! I have one thing that needs improvement: I need the max date for each status to match the min date of the next status, like this:
Status max update (Open) == Status min update (Inactive/Block)
2024-06-24 02:00:46.040 == 2024-06-24 02:00:46.040
Status max update (Inactive/Block) == Status min update (Closed)
2024-07-05 13:13:02.133 == 2024-07-05 13:13:02.133
Could you please offer a solution for this?
